# Android - no bluetooth discovery timeout on nexus devices

Tags: android, bluetooth

I write a little app that turn on BT discovery for 120sec
it work perfect on many devices like: galaxy 6s(5.0.1) and galaxy 6s(6.0.1) and Meizu mx4, onePlus 1 and more, --except all the nexus devices they have android version 6.0.1--
this is the code-

```
Intent discoverableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION,120); 
startActivity(discoverableIntent);
```

I add those permissions to manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
```

why it's not working only on Nexus devices ?

Comment: have you read the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html)?

Comment: yes it's not helping

Comment: someone know why it's happened only on Nexus devices?

Answer (score 0):

if the version of Android are you running this is Android 6.x, I believe you need to add the ACCESS_COURSE_LOCATION permission to your manifest. For example:

Check This Link :- https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-hardware-id

To access the hardware identifiers of nearby external devices via Bluetooth and Wi-Fi scans, your app must now have the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION or ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION permissions

Comment: I have those two permissions, the problem is that my code makes the nexus phone discoverable, and a message that says to agree to make my phone discoverable for 120 sec appears and I press on ok, the problem is that it's not happened for 120sec but! is discoverable forever even more than 1hr, I think that it's google bug?

Comment: I think this not google bug there might be some device Bluetooth settings change. Can you please try to change Bluetooth scanning settings then check your code.

I had tested the code on nexus 5x and its working fine, device is not discoverable after 120 sec.

Comment: which Android version you have? , by the way at nexus 6P with android 7 it not reproducing, and before the upgrade, it happened.

Comment: Device :- nexus 5x & Android version :- 7.0